# Can I swap two IMEIs that I own?

Tags: united-states

I'm aware that cloning IMEIs and swapping them to bypass a blacklist is illegal, but can I legally swap the [IMEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity) on two phones that I own?

Both of these phones are "clean," meaning neither of them are reported as stolen and they both work. I can also prove that I am the owner of both phones.